# Opening an about box using MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm, modal-dialog, about-box

I'm working on a new WPF application and I'm trying to stay as close to the MVVM pattern as I can.  My XAML files right now have no codebehinds, and all my interactivity is achieved using Josh Smith's RelayCommand class and commands in my ViewModel classes.

This worked great until I started working on the housekeeping tasks, such as an about box and a system preferences page.  I want to have these as modal dialogs, but if I create a RelayCommand to open these pages, I'll be creating a dependency on the view within my view model.

This strikes me as against the grain of the MVVM pattern.

Is there an established method for creating new windows (modal and/or modeless) within the MVVM pattern without creating a dependency?  It seems the only way I can keep the ViewModel clean is to create a Click event handler in the XAML codebehind file and create the new view within the old view.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to handle this is to implement a service that provides Views to ViewModels. Views register with the service and ViewModels can request dialogs from the service. This is an example of the Gang of Four [mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my Modal Dialogs solution for Silverlight 4:

[Modal dialogs with MVVM and Silverlight 4](http://blog.roboblob.com/2010/01/19/modal-dialogs-with-mvvm-and-silverlight-4/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321346/error-window-show-modal-in-mvvm-wpf) about why the Window class itself is a ViewModel, so you can use it directly from your ViewModel without worries.

Answer (score 0):

Laurent Bugnion has a weak-referenced mediator, in which he uses it to show dialog messages.  Along with the message that is broadcast, a callback delegate is sent for the subscriber to execute.  You could use the same concept to show an about dialog.  Check out DialogMessage.cs [from the source here](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/).

Answer (score 0):

We use Controller classes which are responsible for the UI Workflow. They create the modal windows and they mediate between various ViewModels.

How you can open a modal window with the View-Model-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern is shown in the ViewModel sample application here:

WPF Application Framework (WAF)

http://waf.codeplex.com